# How can I Authenticate to this HTTPS SOAP Service?

Tags: delphi, soap, https

I am trying to create a little tool that will monitor how much bandwidth I have used and how much I have remaining from my ISP. They have a SOAP service which I must authenticate my UserName and Password and validate the client then I will get 2 GUIDS that must be passed into the function that will return the usage statistics from an array. These are then cached for 1 hour and I must authenticate again.

I have used the WSDL Importer from within Delphi 2010 and it has generated me a Unit. (I am not really sure that I should post this as it is quite large)?

I am trying to authenticate the first part with my Username and Password with the code below:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAuthClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fGUID: string;
begin
  HTTPRIO1.URL := 'https://webservices.zen.co.uk/broadband/v3.11/serviceengine.asmx?WSDL';
  try
    fGUID := (HTTPRIO1 as ServiceEngineSoap).Authenticate(edtUserName.Text,edtPassword.Text);
    Label1.Caption := fGUID;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    Memo1.Lines.Text := E.Message;
  end;
end;
```

The above code always returns the Error below:

> Header http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:Action for ultimate recipient is required but not present in the message.

I have tried using the WSDLLocation instead with the Service and the Port:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAuthClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fGUID: string;
begin
  HTTPRIO1.WSDLLocation := 'https://webservices.zen.co.uk/broadband/v3.11/serviceengine.asmx?WSDL';
  HTTPRIO1.Service := 'ServiceEngine';
  HTTPRIO1.Port := 'ServiceEngineSoap';
  try
    fGUID := (HTTPRIO1 as ServiceEngineSoap).Authenticate(edtUserName.Text,edtPassword.Text);
    Label1.Caption := fGUID;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    Memo1.Lines.Text := E.Message;
  end;
end;
```

This will always generate the Error below:

> Unable to retrieve the URL endpoint for Service/Port 'ServiceEngine'/'ServiceEngineSoap' from WSDL 'https://webservices.zen.co.uk/broadband/v3.11/serviceengine.asmx?WSDL'

What am I doing wrong here? If I should actually send a Header then how would I do this to authenticate myself to the service?

Comment: please post the unit generated by the WSDL importer, I think it will help.

Comment: I have just tried to edit my question to include the Unit but it is too long: body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 53992

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SOAPHTTPClient.THTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode)

> if the server requires authentication, use the properties of the
>   THTTPReqResp object to provide the necessary information

It's in the THTTPReqResp object that you set the user/pw  (HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.UserName := 'xxx'; HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.Password := 'yyy')

Also note from the docs on using HTTPS:

> THTTPReqResp uses WinInet to establish a connection to the server.
>   Wininet.dll must be installed on the client system. wininet.dll is
>   found in the Windows system directory if you have IE3 or higher
>   installed. WinInet has the advantage that it provides support for
>   secure connections (https). To use WinInet, compile your project
>   without the USE_INDY symbol defined

However, it looks like this user/pw may only be used in a Proxy situation according to the post below.  Follow Jean-Marie Babet's link to the original workaround given from 2007 if they still haven't fixed this:

https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=58755&tstart=0

Here's the workaround:

> All you have to do is handle the OnBeforePost event on the
>   HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode component and use InternetSetOption. Here's an
>   example from a sample that talks to MapPoint (MapPoint.NET uses
>   'digest' authentication - a variant of 'basic' authentication):

```
procedure TTestMapPointRender.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
  const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
  UserName: string;
  PassWord: string;
begin
  UserName := GetWSToken('MapPoint', 'UserName');
  Password := GetWSToken('MapPoint', 'Password');
  if not InternetSetOption(Data,
               INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME,
               PChar(UserName),
               Length(UserName)) then
     raiseException(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

  if not InternetSetOption(Data,
               INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD,
               PChar(Password),
               Length (Password)) then
     raiseException(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is the GetWSToken? I have added wininet but I cannot find much info. It is undeclared identifier.

Comment: GetWSToken looks like a utility method custom to the implementation... You simply replace that with whatever method you need to lookup the user/pw required.